# Liferay 7 - Multiple resourceCommands in single class?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

I'm about to move from Liferay 6.2 to 7. I'v been using Spring in Liferay 6.2, but apparently using Spring on 7 doesn't have benefits of using component specific configuration via classes.

It seems to me that every single Liferay 7 ajax endpoint needs to be configured as single command class, leading to dozens of files per logical model/controller.

On LR 6.2 Spring I have had single controller which wraps every resource-endpoint to single file. Is this possible on LR 7 with components? If LR7 enforces to use single class-file per command, while is this forced instead of supporting single class with multiple methods (design-wise)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that you're talking about the `serveResource` phase of a portlet when you talk about Ajax endpoints.

If you go the ResourceCommand route: Yes, you'll need a single resource command for every named resource handler. However, you do not have to go this way, you can still implement in a single portlet class.

The one difference:

You're in control of your own portlet, which means that you can easily change and update it should you need a different behavior. Thus it's not a problem to go with a single (potentially larger) portlet class.

On the other hand Liferay's built-in components sometimes need to be updated by others (e.g. you), so separating them out into many smaller services is a great thing for Liferay users who intend to modify tiny aspects: They only need to override the single ResourceCommand they have in mind for their change.

Thus, you'll see excessive use of the ResourceCommand pattern all over Liferay. But you can totally ignore this for your own code and continue with individual named resource handlers in a single class.

That being said, some pseudocode (only written here, never compiled and tested) for such a portlet:

```
@Component(...)
public class MyPortlet extends GenericPortlet {
    public void serveResource(ResourceRequest req, ResourceResponse res) {
      String name = req.getParameter("name");
      // handle request for named activity
    }
}
```

(Edit of the code: Apologies, I completely mixed up the Action and Resource phases, rather suggested "Action" logic than "Resource")

And yet another alternative is to ditch the portlet implementation and just implement a Web Service - either through Liferay's Service Builder, or through REST. There are plenty of samples available for these cases as well, but your question appeared as if you were going the portlet route.

Comment: The problem is that I haven't seen a single example on how I could route multiple endpoints within LR 7 MVC in single class (one endpoint = switch-case-hell). Ideally, like in .NET MVC, I'v been able to write all methods +additional logical methods ("validate" etc) to single controller class, and use annotation PER method to configure it's route and user-group validation. In LR7 it seems that @component annotation only targets the class, not the methods of class.

Alternatively in PHP Laravel I could write every method to controller and use single router-file to tell routes & authentication.

Comment: Yes, @Component (it's an OSGi Declarative Service annotation) targets the class. See the edited answer for a sample.

Comment: Thanks for giving clear example. Could you specify which parameter on url-generation specifies foo or bar? Is it a query-parameter or friendly-url route, such as /user/foo or /user/bar  ?

Comment: I've edited my question - sorry for mixing up action- and resource-handling. You can choose freely. With the friendly-url route: You decide for yourself, which one it is.